# Gmagick set density before loading PDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, gmagick

Converting a PDF to an image using Gmagick in PHP renders a very poor quality image.

The solution in Imagick was to call `setResolution(x,y)` ***before*** loading the PDF file. This would change the -density option.

There is no `setResolution(x,y)` in Gmagick, and unfortunately, calling `setimageresolution(x,y)` just throws an error:

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'GmagickException' with message 'Can not process empty Gmagick object'**

Calling `setimageresolution(x,y)` after loading the PDF has no effect, and I can't find a way to set the -density option before loading the file.

***EDIT:*** I would be happy for a way to set the default density system-wide.  I do have root access.

Comment: I found no solution, maybe a bug, maybe not yet implemented. `gmagick` looks like a dead end to me. There's almost no documentation, only a very shallow one on PHP.net. No user-contributed notes (not that I'm missing them, but...). [Outdated releases](https://pecl.php.net/package/gmagick), [orphaned issue tracker](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&package_name[]=gmagick), last commit [2 years ago](https://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/gmagick/).

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into a similar problem and solved it with the following code:

```
$image = new \Gmagick();
$image->setresolution(300, 300);
$image->readimage('sample.pdf[0]');
```

Note that the `setresolution` method is not documented in PHP anywhere, but it seems to work – at least for me.